# How to get OPC DA dynamic ports?

Tags: opc-da

I need to parse OPC DA packets to get the dynamic ports that clients and server use. By observing the packets captured by Wireshark, I found that the ISystemActivator request and response packets are both encrypted. I know that the dynamic ports information are in the ISystemActivator response packet. What do I need to do to decrypt the encrypted stub data?